# Lighttpd rewrite rules for WordPress Multisite in a subdirectory

Tags: rewrite, lighttpd

I need a Lighttpd rewrite rule for a WordPress Multisite in a subdirectory for my local install.

```
  # Rewrite
  url.rewrite-final = (
    "^/([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-json.*)" => "/index.php/$2",
    "^/index\.php$" => "/$0",
    "^/([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$" => "/$1wp-admin/",
    "^/([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*)" => "/$2",
    "^/([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)" => "/$2",
    "^/(.*)/?$" => "/index.php"
  )
```

works for an install in the webserver root folder, in my case 'htdocs'. But how can I move the whole Wordpress install to a subfolder of 'htdocs' and redirect accordingly?

I need to move this install, because I would like to start development other sites on localhost without losing access to my former projects. How to move a wordpress blog, even multisite, is common for me, but i lack the knowledge for lightpd. Please help!